# Cannot convert value of type 'Range<Int>?' to expected argument type 'Range<String.Index>?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I'm getting an error when trying to pass into `string.range(of:, options:, range:, locale)`

Specifically, for the range modifier I tried passing in
`Range(remainingRange)` with `remainingRange = NSMakeRange(0, string.count)`

However, the error seems to indicate it's of a mismatched type where there is no `String.Index`: `'Range<Int>?' to expected argument type 'Range<String.Index>?'`.

I'm not sure why this would be an issue as just passing the range in objective c works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Swift strings cannot be subscripted by `Int` indexes because the length of the characters are flexible.

Replace

```
NSMakeRange(0, string.count)
```

with

```
NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string)
```

or – better – just omit the `range` and the `locale` parameters.